# How to accept the code the suggested by vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

[image]

Actually I have started to write a for loop, My VS Code AI or GitHub Copilot I don't know what it is but completed my code, but I don't know how to accept the code when I press enter or space the code disappears is there any shortcut to print the code. I am noob to VS Code and Stack Overflow, hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: Note that there *are* cases where pressing **Tab** does not work. [Here](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/1011#issue-996151712)'s a GitHub Issue that might help then.

Answer (score 9):

Simply hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to accept CoPilot's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

enter or space will not do that, maybe try pressing the "tab" key, it will automatically fill in the code.